# custom js product page

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm trying to execute a custom js on a product page in a way to get an color swatch selected on page load only if there is only one option. This is the script:

```
var number = $('.swatch-attribute .color').length;
if(number==1){
    $('.swatch-attribute .color').click();
}
});
```

In the console it works but not in Magento, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Try once below code :

`<script>
        require([
            "jquery"
        ], function($) {
            var number = $('.swatch-attribute .color').length;
            if(number==1){
                $('.swatch-attribute .color').click();
            }

        });
</script>`