# How to execute js code for a specific product?

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, template, frontend

I need to execute javascript code for one specific product on the product page. How can I do that?

Magento version: 2.2.5

---

I found some answers on the web, but they don't work for me:

1) [custom js product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222874/custom-js-product-page)

Doesn't tell where the js code should live

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906109/magento-add-inline-javascript-to-product-page-via-layout-update-xml-code

M1 only - does not work for M2 for me

Comment: You need to override the template and perform the product check that you are looking for.

Comment: Oh - sounds complicated. Is there no way to just add some javascript to the body of the product page?

Comment: If this is a custom theme, then you can. If they are kernel files, then no.